# Custom d3interval creation

Tags: d3.js

I want to create an interval in such a way so that the first callback happens immediately and subsequent callbacks happen at the specified del. Is it possible inside a single `d3.interval`?

```js
console.log(new Date());
const del = 1000;

let ticker = d3.interval(e => {
    console.log(new Date(), 1);
    if (e > 3000)(ticker.stop())
}, del)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't "possible in a single `d3.interval`". `ds.interval` doesn't have that capability.

Instead, break out the anonymous function to a variable, start the interval, then call the function directly.

```
console.log(new Date());
const del = 1000;
const intervalFunc = e => {
    console.log(new Date(), 1);
    if (e > 3000)(ticker.stop())
};
let ticker = d3.interval(intervalFunc, del)
intervalFunc();
```

Comment: I can sequence 2 intervals, one with `0` delay and the other one with 'del`. Breaking out the function does not result in the desired end result.